Prove that $\sum\limits_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{bc}{\sqrt[3]{a^4+7}}\le\frac{3}{2}$ for $a, b, c > 0$ with $a+b+c=3$

For $a,b,c>0$, $a+b+c=3$ 
Show that $$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} \frac{bc}{\sqrt[3]{a^4+7}}\le\frac{3}{2}.$$

My attempt.
$$\sum \frac{bc}{\sqrt[3]{a^4+7}}\le\sum\frac{bc}{\sqrt[3]{2.2.(a+1)}}=\frac{1}{2}\sum\sqrt[3]{\frac{2bc.2bc.2bc}{2.2.(a+1)}}$$
$$\le\frac{1}{3}(\sum ab+\sum\frac{ab}{c+1})\le\frac{1}{3}(\frac{(\sum a)^2}{3}+\sum\frac{ab}{c+1})$$
$$=\frac{1}{3}(3+\sum\frac{ab}{c+1})=1+\frac{1}{3}\sum \frac{ab}{c+1}$$
I can't evalute $\sum \frac{ab}{c+1} \le \frac{1}{2}$
Can anyone give me hint?

What is this summing over?

@Cristof012 it is a cyclic sum with respect to $a,b,c$.

It is not true that $\displaystyle\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{ab}{c+1}\leqslant\frac32$ indeed for $a=\frac32$, $b=\frac1{10}$, $c=\frac75$, it results that $;a+b+c=3;$ and  $$\sum_{\text{cyc}}\frac{ab}{c+1}!=!\frac1{16}!+!\frac{21}{11}!+!\frac7{125}!>!\frac1{16}!+!\frac{19}{10}!+!\frac7{125}!=!\frac{4037}{2000}!>!2$$

Remark. In OP, $\frac{1}{3}(\sum ab+\sum\frac{ab}{c+1}) \le \frac32$ is true. Here is alternative way. The form of (1) is nice but the proof of it is not so simple since we need to raise both sides to the 3rd power.
We can prove that, for all $u\in [0, 3]$,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{u^4 + 7}} \le
\frac12 + (-1/12)(u - 1). \tag{1}$$
(Note: The RHS is the first order Taylor approximation of the LHS around $u = 1$.)
Using (1), it suffices to prove that
$$\sum_{\mathrm{cyc}} bc \cdot \frac{7-a}{12} \le \frac32,$$
or
$$18 + 3abc - 7(ab+bc+ca) \ge 0. \tag{2}$$
Using degree three Schur inequality in this form
$$9abc + (a + b + c)^3 \ge 4(a + b + c)(ab + bc + ca),$$
we have
$$3abc \ge 4(ab + bc + ca) - 9.\tag{3}$$
Using (3), we have
\begin{align*}
 18 + 3abc - 7(ab + bc + ca)
 &= 18 + 4(ab + bc + ca) - 9 - 7(ab + bc + ca)\\
 &= 9 - 3(ab + bc + ca) \\
 &\ge 0
\end{align*}
where we use $ab + bc + ca \le (a + b + c)^2/3 = 3$. Thus, (2) is true.
We are done.
